# Log model interpretation of bounded, non-logged independent variable

Tags: interpretation, lognormal-distribution

in a simplified form, the model i am working with is the following:

log(crime rate) = -0.17 * NDVI

where NDVI is land vegetation index - a bounded variable with range [-1,1] (in my actual data it ranges from about 0.26 to 0.62) where higher scores indicate "more green."

Because the regressor is bounded, it feels a little strange to say "a one unit increase in vegetation index is associated with a 17% decrease in crime rate."

would this be equivalent to saying "a 50% increase in vegetation index is associated with a 17% decrease in crime rate" since my variable's range is 2?

alternatively, how else could i interpret this coefficient? e.g. "a 10% increase in vegetation index is associated with _________."?

Comment: Why not rescale the index by 100 so that a 1 units change is more sensible or convert it to quartiles or deciles?

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov, that's a great point and was a consideration for interpretability (also considered logging the index). the practical side of things is that this request came from a reviewer for an article submission, and i preferably would want to just add this short text regarding the interpretation with the variables as-is rather than re-running all my regressions and overhauling my tables/text.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, $$E[\ln y \vert x, z]=\alpha + \beta \cdot x + \gamma \cdot z.$$ Here $z$ stands for other covariates.

Taking the derivative of that with respect to $x$, you get $$\frac{1}{y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \beta \approx \frac{\frac{\Delta y}{y}}{\Delta x}.$$ This means that $$ \beta \approx \frac{\frac{\Delta y}{y}}{\Delta x},$$  so that $100 \cdot \beta $ can be interpreted as the percentage change in $y$ for a one unit change in $x$. This is a semi-elasticity.

It is fairly straightforward to take rewrite this as

$$\beta \cdot x \approx \frac{\frac{\Delta y}{y}}{\frac{\Delta x}{x}}.$$

Since $x$ is a variable, you can calculate the average elasticity in your sample like this:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_i^{N} \beta \cdot x_i=\beta \cdot \bar x$$

In your case, $-0.17 \cdot \bar x$ would be the quantity your reviewer wants. It tells you the average percentage change in $y$ for a 1% change in $x$.